# Fix items on top of each other?

Tags: javascript, vis.js

In my vis.js timeline some items get stack on top of each other so that I can't see the ones that's in the back. I have tried adding margin, but that just makes the other ones (that look good) get put further away from each other.

Is this a common problem and how do I fix it?

I have checked the docs, but can't find an answer. http://visjs.org/docs/timeline/

[image: vis.js items stacked on top of each other]

Comment: Just use `stack` option and set it to true. By default, stack is set on true.

Comment: @Zooly He have to set it to false, not true

Comment: @Faly are you sure? On documentation it's said that if true, items will be stacked without overlaping

Comment: @Zooly I'm sure, I'm using vis.js timeline right now

Comment: @Faly I was using it for a while, and in my project it's set on true to get expected behavior :/

Comment: Thank you for quick answers, but if I set stack to false I get this... https://i.imgur.com/pDLgNqw.jpg. I have tried both true and false. True is what I have as default.

Comment: Maybe you have to play with the height property, stack property is not a solution

Comment: @Faly I have tried that too, but that don't seem to matter unfortunately.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone else having the same problem, this is what I found.

- If the item is `range` type, it needs to have an `end` value or else it won't stack.
- I had to apply a `maxHeight`to the **timeline** options and had to set `scrollVertical` to `true`.

You can find more information about the configuration options here: 
https://visjs.github.io/vis-timeline/docs/timeline/#Configuration_Options